# Getting married in the US on an ESTA

Tags: usa, marriage, esta

I am getting married to my American fiancée in the US this summer.

We are currently living together outside of the US (and, should it matter, also outside of my own country of origin, Germany) and would be only visiting the US for a few weeks around the wedding, so an ESTA would be sufficient, time span-wise. I do not plan to stay in the states afterwards.

**Question** Should I still get an immigrant fiancé visa? If not, would I need to convince the immigration officer of my good intentions of not being an immigrant, and how would I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Because you do not plan to immigrate to the US, you should not apply for a fiancé(e) visa, the point of which is to provide a path to a green card.  Instead, you can enter with ESTA under the visa waiver program.  You may be suspected of intending to immigrate, though, because the immigration officer is required by law to presume that it is your intention to do so.  You should therefore have evidence of your life at home, and probably also of your fiancée's life there, to overcome the presumption that you intend to immigrate.

Useful evidence could include a lease or ownership papers for your home, evidence that you live there together, and evidence that you both have stable professional lives there.